# How to open file in existing Vim instance instead of getting "existing swapfile " warning

Tags: visual-studio, vim

I want Vim to reuse the currently existing instance if it exists. Usually, Vim pops up a warning about an existing swap file. Specifically, this is for switching between Vim and Visual Studio. (I know about ViEmu, but it doesn't work with Visual Studio Express.)

Comment: @Weldon: I'm offering easy rep to anyone who wants it: If someone just copies my answer, I will accept the answer and remove the answer from my question.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working on my system.

With Vim open editing a source file:
1. If I open a new terminal and try to edit the same file, I get the swap file message.
2. If I pop out to :shell and try and open the same file, I get the swap file message.

Comment: @alesplin: are you using Vim version 7 or later? Version 7's SwapExists autocommand event is required. Perhaps this is one difference with the --servername/--remote-silent way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Poster's Solution:**

**Solution:**
There is a plugin in the standard distribution of Vim: runtime/macros/editexisting.vim. Just copy it to the Vim plugins directory.

**Extra details for Visual Studio Integration:** Follow [these steps](http://kevin-berridge.blogspot.com/2008/10/vim-to-and-from-visual-studio.html) to add Vim as an external tool and assign a convenient keyboard shortcut:

- Title: Vim
- Command: C:\Program Files\Vim\vim70\gvim.exe
- Arguments: +$(CurLine) "$(ItemPath)"
- Initial directory: $(SolutionDir)

Note I use slightly different settings so the cursor is set to the column from VS and centered in Vim:

- Arguments: **+"call cursor($(CurLine),$(CurCol))" +"normal zz"** $(ItemPath)
- Initial directory: $(FileDir)

Then set VS to [automatically load chanages made from Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio):

> In order to effectively use the two
>   together and make sure .NET does not
>   complain about its files changing,
>   goto Tools > Options > Environment >
>   Documents and ensure these two options
>   are checked:  Detect when file is
>   changed outside the environment. 
>   Auto-load changes (if not currently
>   modified inside the environment).

Finally set Vim to [automatically load changes made from VS](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Calling_gvim_from_MS_Visual_Studio):

> :set autoread

---

**My Solution**

Similar, but subtly different:  Save this to a .settings file and import.  Uses `--servername` and `--remote-call` to reuse existing Vim, tailored for the current solution.

```
<UserSettings>
    <ApplicationIdentity version="8.0"/>
    <ToolsOptions/>
    <Category name="Environment_Group" RegisteredName="Environment_Group">
        <Category name="Environment_ExternalTools" Category="{E8FAE9E8-FBA2-4474-B134-AB0FFCFB291D}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_ExternalTools" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.Command">gvim.exe</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.Arguments">--servername $(SolutionFileName) --remote-silent +"call cursor($(CurLine),$(CurCol))" "$(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt)"</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.InitialDirectory">$(ItemDir)</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.SourceKeyName"/>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.UseOutputWindow">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.PromptForArguments">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.CloseOnExit">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.IsGUIapp">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.SaveAllDocs">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.UseTaskList">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.Unicode">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.Package">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="edit with v&amp;im.NameID">0</PropertyValue>
        </Category>
    </Category>
</UserSettings>
```

Comment: Have you updated your `.settings` file at all? I noticed that Visual Studio uses `.vssettings` files now and when I export my external tool settings the schema appears to be different as well. I'm using VS 2013..

Comment: This answer is probably way out of date now.